# Javascripts for an Interactive network visualisation

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, visualization, interactive

I have been looking for some javascript code that I can use to create something similar to [this](http://politilines.periscopic.com/).

I need something that can show the links between boxes when clicked on/hovered over. As of this point I have not yet been able to determine what the name of this particular type visualisation is.

I have already looked at:

- Google Charts
- d3.js
- graphdracula
- processing.js
- Raphael
- Protovis
- MooWheel
- PlotKit

Comment: That site is using Raphael. It's entirely custom, though. There is no plug-and-play component for this. You may be able to get started with d3's tree view: http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html

Answer (score 0):

You may want to focus in learning D3.JS because it seems to meet your requirements, and it does things very well.

The two vector graphic libraries you can focus are Raphael and D3.JS, but D3.JS is much more powerful with data binding. You can find a large amount of resources through the internet for D3JS.

Here are some of the tutorials that I think useful:
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tutorials

Examples gallery is here:
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery

Besides, D3js is the successor of Protovis, you can find this information at the following Wiki:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protovis#Context

Google Charts may have some good features, but it's not a very active and well up to date as some other vector graphic tools.

For other libraries, I think should not spend much time.

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly boxes, but more fluid network layout.

http://datavisualizationsoftwarelab.com/

Graphs are pure HTML5, no dependancies on other libs, thus easy to integrate with any JS framework (such as jQuery). Uses Canvas for rendering, has full multi-touch support for navigation, interaction and exploration of data.

An example of network chart:

[image]

Charts come with extensive API and Settings, so you can control every aspect of the charts.